# How can I step through and evaluate variables in JavaFx source using Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, javafx

Using Netbeans, I have set a break-point in the TableColumn class of the JavaFX sdk lib.
When dubugging my application, the break-point stops correctly, but the following message is displayed in the variables panel:

> "Netbeans: Variable information is not available, source compiled
>   without -g option."

How can I step through JavaFx sources to debug my application

Note:

1. My Project compile settings has `Generate Debugging Info` set to true.
2. My Maven compiler  configuration does NOT have `<debug>false</debug>`.
3. I am using JDK 1.8 Update 45.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project properties -> Compiling -> "Additional compiler options" and add "-g"

Comment: Setting the "Generate Debugging Info" check-box essentially does the same thing. My problem is not that I cannot inspect my projects values, it's that I cannot inspect the java runtime's JavaFX libraries, which are already compiled. I believe this is accomplished somehow in IntelliJ, wondering how I can do it in Netbeans as well.